# How to utilize the output probabilities from a probabilisitic classifier?

Tags: probability, classification

Can anybody please explain that in simple words: how can we correctly use probabilities given by some classifiers along with the predicted class values?

Let us consider some implementation of a Naive Bayes classifier that works with Gaussian priors. As an output, for each test instance we have a true class label, a predicted class label, and a probability. How can we interpret this probability? Consider, the threshold is 0.5. If probability for some test instance is 0.75, it belongs to the positive class. What if the correct label for that instance is a negative class, i.e. classifier makes an error but give a high probability?

Some interpret that probability as "confidence" in a non-statistical sense. Some use these probabilities as parameters of a function they try to optimize. That confuses me.

For example, one owns a designer boutique and re-sells items bought cheap online. He wants to minimize costs associated with items that are not truly described (like a sweater have been worn a lot, but description says "like new"). Assume, our classifier is built on features extracted from description, seller's score, feedback, etc. We try to predict, if the item sold on ebay is truly described. If the classifier assigns it to a positive class (item is as described), one can place a higher bid. The maximum bid price one wants to pay for a truly new sweater is multiplied by the probability the sweater is as described. This is a naive model, of course. My observation is that the amount of incorrectly classified instances with high probabilities can be quite high, so it does not work for any kind of optimization. But the example I gave seems to be a popular use of probabilistic classifier. And that probability cannot be interpreted as common sense confidence, is that right?

Comment: If you treat the probabilities as ... probabilities, then if the results are poor you classifier isn't doing a very good job (maybe a different one would do better, or maybe their just isn't enough information in the training data). Note that some classifiers, such as SVM, will generate biased probabilities that need to be re-calibrated in order to be accurate.

Comment: That is an interesting point you have brought. Re-calibrated how? Has anybody done that? Please, share a reference.

Comment: @Bogdanovist do you know any classifiers that do not generate biased probabilities ? And how would you re-calibrate the biased probabilities of a given classifier in order to be more accurate ? If you make a detailed answer abut this would be awesome.